# Module errorr for airflow oracle hook

Tags: dockerfile, airflow

I am trying to set up an Oracle database connection on airflow.
I am getting this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.oracle' when using: from airflow.provideres.oracle.hooks.oracle import OracleHook

Part of my `dag` file:

```
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.providers.oracle.hooks.oracle import OracleHook

def exe_query_oracle_hook():
        hook = OracleHook(oracle_conn_id="oracle_conn")
        df = hook.get_pandas_df(sql='SELECT * FROM TABLE')
        print(df.to_string())
```

I tried installing `pip install apache-airflow-providers-oracle` and most were already required, my current version is 2.1.0. I also followed the docs: [airflow building custom images](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html). Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.0

ARG ORACLE_VERSION=11.2.0.4.0
ARG ORACLE_SHORT_VER=11204
ENV CLIENT_ZIP=instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-${ORACLE_VERSION}.zip
ENV SDK_ZIP=instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-${ORACLE_VERSION}.zip
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle
ENV TNS_ADMIN ${ORACLE_HOME}/network/admin

WORKDIR ${ORACLE_HOME}
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get -yq install unzip curl \
        && apt-get clean

COPY dockerfiles/${CLIENT_ZIP} ${ORACLE_HOME}/${CLIENT_ZIP}
COPY dockerfiles/${SDK_ZIP} ${ORACLE_HOME}/${SDK_ZIP}
RUN unzip ${ORACLE_HOME}/${CLIENT_ZIP} && unzip ${ORACLE_HOME}/${SDK_ZIP} \
        && rm -f *.zip
VOLUME ["${TNS_ADMIN}"]

RUN apt-get -yq install libaio1 \
        && apt-get autoremove \
        && apt-get clean \
        && echo ${ORACLE_HOME} > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf \
        && mkdir -p ${TNS_ADMIN} \
        && ldconfig \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir apache-airflow-providers-oracle

USER 1001
```

Not sure what else to try, can anyone please provide some assistance? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the pip install as airflow user, currently you run it as root.

```
...
USER 1001
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir apache-airflow-providers-oracle
```

Comment: And if you use the 3.1.0 provider it will use the upgraded, renamed python-oracledb driver which doesn't need Instant Client, see https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-oracle/stable/index.html and https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a